# Why don't the .url in Django template link to the "upload_to=" directory of the model?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I made a template to list documents with a download link, but instead of linking to :

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/documents/mydoc.csv

it links to :

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/mydoc.csv

**In myapp/models.py**

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

**In myapp/templates/myapp/list.html**

```
    <ul>
    {% for document in documents %}
        <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

document.docfile.url links to media/mydoc.csv but the file is stored into media/documents/mydoc.csv

**Versions**

- Python : 3.7.2
- Django : 2.1.7
- OS : Windows 10

**In myapp/views.py**

```
def myview(request):

    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'myapp/list.html', {'documents': documents})
```

**In myapp/urls.py**

```
app_name = 'myapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('myview/', views.myview, name='myview'),
]
```

**In myproject/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**In settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Since it is my fist Django app (and first webapp ever) I guess I missed something very basic. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
I think you are missing "/" after documents as per documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/db/models/fields/files/#FileField

Comment: I had some big hope seeing your comment but unfortunatly this does not correct the bug... It seems that object.field.url is not aware of the right path...

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")  does not change the results.

Comment: I managed to get the right path using document.docfile.name = os.path.join('documents', document_name) generating the document. While the path is now correct there is still a 404 error. Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/documents/document_name.csv

Comment: The latest has been solved by adding ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) in urls.py. Not sure that it is secure but the site is not public.

Comment: Hi I encountered the same problem. Could you advise how this last correction was made? Where in the urls.py should I add "static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)"

Comment: Figured out now! Also need to add MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in settings. this is so complicated.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that:

```
{{ document.docfile.url }}
```

Is not storing the actual url of the document but adds its name to the media directory url.

So that, if the file is in a subdirectory, it has to be in the name parameter of the file field:

```
document_name = 'document_name.csv'
upload_subdir = 'documents'
document.docfile.name = os.path.join(upload_subdir, document_name)
```

Another point is that the media root has to be declared as a static directory in mysite/urls.py to allow downloads :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This may not be secure as users can download evrything inside as long as they can guess the url. Another option is to create a view function that proceed to the download.

Comment: `FileField.url` calls on the storage to compute the url based on the file _path_ - and it does work as expected so you don't have anything to do to get the proper url path -, And you shouldn't have to add  the staticfiles url for the file's url to be correct either (medias are supposed to be served by your front server on production anyway). IOW, your real issue is elsewhere, and you just managed to hide it (with something that is redundant at best and probe to break when deploying to a production setup).

Comment: NB: I assume you're using the default filesystem storage of course.

Comment: I'm a bit confused then because the doc includes the subdirectory in the name too : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/files/ Afterwards, it is just an internal app that serve a script generated file and will be used by 3 people. But I'm still very interested to know what is going wrong. It is my very first webapp (I'm learned programming a couple of weeks ago) and I'm planning to use Django for a personal project later that will be a real website.

Comment: "I'm a bit confused then because the doc includes the subdirectory in the name too" => yes, that's what it's supposed to do indeed. Both the file's absolute path and the resource url are computed from the relative path (stored in db) and (resp.) the settings MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL.  Why you have an issue and where it comes from is not clear to me and is probably the kind of problems that you can hardly expect to debug without direct access to your computer....

Comment: Just one point, but I think you already understood this so I mention it just in case: if you changed (or added) the `upload_to` _after_ you already created a couple records, the already uploaded files won't be affected by the change (you'd have to write a data migration for this) , only the newly created ones.